# How to select an element based on the class of a previous sibling's descendant

Tags: jquery, css

I want to select the label element to apply a CSS property if the span contains a class with checked value. Here is the code to make it clear:

```
<li>
    <div class="radio">
        <span class="checked"><input style="position: absolute;left: -9999px;" id="28" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="28" checked="checked">
        </span>
    </div>
    <label style="cursor: pointer;display:initial;padding: 1px 7px 5px;border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" for="28">46-48</label>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-51">
        <span><input style="position: absolute;left: -9999px;" id="51" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="51" checked="checked">
        </span>
    </div>
    <label style="cursor: pointer;display:initial;padding: 1px 7px 5px; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" for="51">42-44</label>
</li>
```

So what I want to do is to apply CSS for the first label because the span has the class "checked" (first li) but not the span in the second li.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having the

```
class="checked"
```

On the `<input>` have it on the ancestor `<li>`:

```
<li class="checked">
    <div class="radio">
        <span><input style="position: absolute;left: -9999px;" id="28" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="28" checked="checked"></span>
    </div>
    <label style="cursor: pointer;display:initial;padding: 1px 7px 5px;border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" for="28">46-48</label>
</li>
```

Then you can target the `<span>` like:

```
.checked .radio span {//do stuff}
```

And the label like:

```
.checked label {//do stuff}
```

Answer (score 1):

its easier to do if you put the labels within the spans, then just style the label with the checked class before it. ie

```
.checked label
```

But if you need to keep that label out of the span, then you might need jQuery to help you, unless you add a class to the parent li instead.

example in jQuery

```
$('.checked').parent().parent().find('label').css('opacity','0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `.checked` to its parent, which is going to be an adjacent sibling of `label`, so you can use `+`.

Therefore you can remove the `span`

```js
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $('li').children('div').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).children('div').addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
li .checked + label {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="radio checked">
     <input style="position: absolute;left: -9999px;" id="28" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="28" checked="checked">
    </div>
    <label style="cursor: pointer;display:initial;padding: 1px 7px 5px;border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" for="28">46-48</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="radio " id="uniform-51">
      <input style="position: absolute;left: -9999px;" id="51" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="51" checked="checked">
    </div>
    <label style="cursor: pointer;display:initial;padding: 1px 7px 5px; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" for="51">42-44</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if the second span has the class checked I want the label below it to change the color for example , so how can I do that with css , In fact I don't know which one of the span will have a class="checked"

Comment: my answer does that, I'm going to update it with an example

Answer (score 0):

If you have minimal or no control over the HTML and CSS, using jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('.checked').parent().siblings('label').css('attribute', 'value');
```

Comment: thank you all for your answer . I have tried this but it doesn't work ,$('.attribute_radio').change(function(){
  if($('.attribute_radio').parent().hasClass('checked'))
  {$(this).parent().parent().find('label').addClass('label_selected');}
 });

Comment: I need help please, i'm newbie with jquery , i forgot to mention that i can change the code html because i'm working with CMS prestashop. thank you all for you help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
$('.attribute_radio').click(function(){
    $('.taille label').removeClass('label_selected');
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings('label').addClass('label_selected');

});
```

thank you all